# I cannot emit a simple string using SocketIOClient with c# netcore

Tags: c#, .net-core, socket.io

I cannot emit a simple string using c#. If I use nodejs or html/js as client, it works!

`<PackageReference Include="SocketIOClient" Version="3.0.8" />`

**Server : Linux + nodejs v16**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express()
const server = require('http').Server(app)
const io = require('socket.io')(server, { maxHttpBufferSize: 1e7 })

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log("headers at connection:")
  console.log(socket.handshake.headers)

  socket.on('hi', async function (msg) {
    console.log(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>"+msg.data);
  });

});

server.listen(3000)
console.log("Running on port: " + 3000)
```

**Client: c# Linux netcore 5**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using SocketIOClient;
using System.Text;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("starting Program.cs");
        var client = new SocketIO("http://localhost:3000");   
        client.OnConnected += async (sender, e) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Connected");
            await client.EmitAsync("hi", "im a simple string"); 
            Console.WriteLine("After send");            
        };
        await client.ConnectAsync();
    }
}
```

### Logs

**Client**

`Console.WriteLine("After send");`  is not printed

[image]

**server**

Only the connected event is received

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your `Main` method will complete after the socket is connected. To prevent your application from exiting, use `Console.ReadKey();`

Comment: Thanks!!! It worked. I'm new on c# but this is a failure concept on my part. I was looking for a simple example ready to test unlucky. I will propose to have a complete "Hello world" example in the official repository https://github.com/doghappy/socket.io-client-csharp